# Record exists where a value isn't the actual one

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i have the following code:

```
<% if Set.exists?(:user_id => current_user.id, :exercise_id => !@exercise.id) %>
    to_something ...
<% end %>
```

How can i do the `not @exercise.id` better, because this doesn't work?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That isn't how you do a not-equals query in Rails.

This...

```
Set.exists?(:user_id => current_user.id, :exercise_id => !@exercise.id)
```

is the same as this:

```
Set.exists?(:user_id => current_user.id, :exercise_id => false)
```

If you want to find all records not matching an ID, use this:

```
Set.where('exercise_id != ?', @exercise.id).exists?(:user_id => current_user.id)
```